# JavaScript Remove Object From Array Based on Child Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

Using vanilla JavaScript (supported by the latest version of Chrome, don't worry about IE) and/or lodash/underscore **but no jQuery** how can I take this array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "places": {
      "city": "boston"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "places": {
      "city": "new york"
    }
  }
]
```

...and remove the entire object that has a city of "boston":

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "places": {
      "city": "new york"
    }
  }
]
```

Please keep in mind this array could have dozens of entries. Thank you!

http://plnkr.co/edit/JW3zd6A7OcmihM4CTh1D?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways you can do this is by using filter. For example:

```
var dataWithoutBoston = data.filter(function (el) {
  return el.places.city !== "boston";
});
```

And to make it reusable, you can have a function like this:

```
function removeFromCity(data, name) {
  var result = data.filter(function (el) {
    return el.places.city !== name;
  });
  return result;
};
```

Comment: wrap your function and you can set the city to select as argument